# JavaEE7でリダイレクトした際にFacesMessageが消失する

Tags: java-ee

JavaEE7で、リダイレクトを行う前にFacesMessageに値を詰めても、リダイレクトした先で値が消失してしまいます。消失させずに、保持しておくためにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

リダイレクトのコード

```
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(...);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(msg);
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/something.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
```

something.xhtmlのコード

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
>
    <h:body>
        <h:messages globalOnly="true" /><!-- リダイレクト前に作成したFacesMessageが表示されない -->
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**追記の情報**
Glashfish 4.1.1 では、上記のコードでうまくいきました。
Web Sphere Libarty Profile 8.5.9 では、上記のコードでうまく**いきません**でした。
JavaEEの内部実装による差異ということから、MyFacesとMojarraの差でしょうか？（原因は現時点で特定できていません）

Comment: 英語版SOに同様の質問があるようですが参考になるでしょうか: [Preserving JSF messages after a redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7503503/4506703) (曰く、`redirect`の前に`Flash.doPostPhaseActions`を呼べば取り敢えず動く), [Adding faces message to redirected page using ExternalContext.redirect()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10887870/4506703) (曰く、正しくはメッセージを`INVOKE_APPLICATION`フェーズで追加せよ)

Comment: 英語版SOの参照ありがとうございます。教示いただいた2つの方法を試してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした・・・